# Fetching data from API - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm learning to work with API, redux and thunk now. I get:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function

mistake.

my `api.js` is:

```
export const baseUrl = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Coffee_/_Tea';
```

my `receiptsAction.js` is:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {baseUrl} from '../api';

export const loadRecipes = () => async(dispatch) => {
    const drinksData = await axios.get(baseUrl());
    dispatch({
        type: "FETCH_RECIPES",
        payload: {
            drinks: drinksData.data,
        }
    })
}
```

my `receiptsReducer.js` is:

```
const initState = {
    drinks: {},
}

const receiptsReducer = (state=initState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "FETCH_RECIPES":
            return {
                ...state, drinks: action.payload.drinks
            }
        default:
            return {...state}
    }
}

export default receiptsReducer;
```

my `Home.js` is:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {loadRecipes} from '../actions/receiptsAction';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';


const Home = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(loadRecipes())
    }, [dispatch]);

    return(
        <div>
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

**What I tried:**

1. Checked, if all semicolons are on the right places
2. Checked, if APi is at all valid in `App.js` and it loaded information okay:

```
const coctailHandler = async () => {
  let url = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Coffee_/_Tea";
  const coctails = await axios.get(url);
  console.log(coctails.data.drinks);
}
```

3. Checked, that the data came from API is an object. Also tried to give `const initState = {drinks: {drinks: []},}`. Also tried to write in action `payload: {drinks: drinksData.data.drinks}` with `const initState = {drinks: []}` in the reducer.

Will appreciate any help!

Comment: The error message usually also contains a stack trace with the exact line that caused the error. Where is it coming from?

Comment: @phry it came from` const drinksData = await axios.get(baseUrl());` because baseUrl was not a function. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *calling* `baseUrl` as if it were a function, but it seems like it's just a `string` constant.

```
await axios.get(baseUrl())
```

That should be

```
await axios.get(baseUrl)
```